# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, replace, scrapy

I am getting an attribute error with the replace() function

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I am trying to replace `[` and `'` with an empty string.

```
owner_address = response.xpath('XPATH Expression').getall().replace("[", "").replace("'", "")

owner_address_region = response.xpath('XPATH Expression').getall().replace("[", "").replace("'", "")
```

Output:

### ['SYLVIA A BROWN', '395 BEELAND DR']

To:

### SYLVIA A BROWN, 395 BEELAND DR

Comment: String objects have a method "join" which accepts a list as parameter.

Comment: A list is not a string. You can't replace the brackets. If you want to make a string using the contents of the list, use join. Is this is tripping you up you should review the basic data/object types in python to understand the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `getall()` is a list and you can join list elements using `join`.

A working example would be `"".join(response.xpath('XPATH Expression').getall())`